# How can I display the number 10525.25 as 10.525,25 using regexp with Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, double, regexp-replace

I want to change my number format. If number like 10525.25 I want to make like this = 10.525,25 If number is 40000.25 it must be like 4.000,25 How can I make this in dart? I use Flutter and I will show this in my Text widget.

Answer (score 2):

The `intl` package is what you are looking for. It will format numbers in any locale for you. The format you use in your examples is the same as German, for example:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';


void main () {
  final fmt = NumberFormat("#,##0.00", "de_DE");
  print(fmt.format(10525.25));
  print(fmt.format(40000.25));
}
```

Output:

```
10.525,25
40.000,25
```

You may need to tweak the first parameter to `NumberFormat` to suit your formatting requirement.